# Extending WCF with async code

Tags: wcf, async-await

How do we integrate custom async code in the WCF pipeline, either with await/async or IAsyncResult?

Basically I'm considering the possibility of doing possibly blocking operations during message processing. Two areas for now:

- Logging, where we may want to write to a file / database that exposes async versions (granted, this could be done with a queue and a writer thread)
- Authorization, where we may need to query a database and it also provides async methods.

Now I was looking on the WCF extensibility points and I can't find any hooks with async versions. I'm looking for [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx), [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) and the likes.

Even the new [ClaimsAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.aspx) doesn't seem to provide an async counterpart either.

I feel I'm missing some big part of the puzzle here, because I have this project where all the code uses the new async features and now I can't hook it up here without doing a .Wait() call on the Tasks.

Could someone shed some lights here or tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: I believe WCF (like MVC) only supports `async` at the operation level (for now); the pipeline is not fully `async`. On the other hand, WebAPI was designed with `async` in mind and supports it at all stages in its pipeline.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. If you add that as an answer I'm happy to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe WCF (like MVC) only supports `async` at the operation level (for now); the pipeline is not fully `async`. On the other hand, WebAPI was designed with `async` in mind and supports it at all stages in its pipeline.